# Regex mix of at least 2 characters (alphabetic, numeric, punctuation, special character)

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression for a password field that checks to see if the input contains a mix of at least two characters sets (alphabetic, numeric, punctuation, special character). In addition, the first and last character cannot be numeric and the length must be at least 8 characters long.

I have never dealt with conditional logic for regular expressions, so it's probably why I'm having such a hard time. So far, this (but it's not working as intended):

```
(?=.{8,})(\d.*[a-zA-Z])|(?=.{8,})([a-zA-Z].*\d)|(?=.{8,})(\W.*\d)|(?=.{8,})(\d.*\W)|(?=.{8,})(\W.*[a-zA-Z])|(?=.{8,})([a-zA-Z].*\W)|(?=.{8,})([a-z].*[A-Z])|(?=.{8,})([A-Z].*[a-z])
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I wouldn't do this with a single regex. Why not run it through a set of simpler ones, just to save yourself the inevitable maintenance headaches down the line? Something like (in order, in pseudocode):

```
// First and last are non-numeric and length check
if (!regex_check(pass, /^[^0-9].{6}.*[^0-9]$/)) return false

regexes = {/[a-zA-Z]/, /[0-9]/, /\p{P}|\p{Sc}|\^/} // Different character categories

numCategories = 0
for r in regex
    if (regex_check(pass, r)) numCategories += 1

if numCategories >= 2 return true
return false
```